# Save all data into json file but getting only last index

Tags: json, go, networking, web-crawler

First I am trying to fetch data from URL then again running same URL but with new parameter, these parameter's are stored from first URL then fetching again data from new URL's and then trying to store all data in JSON file but this only storing the last value.
I want to save all data into JSON file

````
    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "net"`enter code here`
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strings"
    )

    type Domains struct {
        Domain string `json:"domain"`
        IP     string `json:"ip"`
    }

    func main() {
        //fetching body of the given url
        url, err := http.Get("http://s.tutree.com:7635/v1/groups")
        Error(err)
        defer url.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(url.Body)
        Error(err)
        converter := string(body)
        trimdata := strings.Split(converter, "\n")
        // fmt.Println(trimdata)
        for _, data := range trimdata {
            urls, err := http.Get("http://s.tutree.com:7635/v1/" + data)
            Error(err)
            defer urls.Body.Close()
            data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(urls.Body)
            Error(err)
            converter := string(data)
            trim := strings.Split(converter, "\n")
            // fmt.Println(converter)
            for _, domains := range trim {
                // fmt.Println(string(domains))
                convertdomain2ip(string(domains))
                // writeFile(domains)
            }
        }
        // fmt.Println("file written successfully")
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    func Error(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }

    //Write data into json file
    func convertdomain2ip(name string) {
        addr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Resolution error", err.Error())
            // os.Exit()
        }
        typeconvert := addr.String()
        var data []Domains
        // for _, names := range trimagain {
        data = append(data, Domains{
            Domain: name,
            IP:     typeconvert,
        })
        // }
        write, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "")
        // fmt.Println(string(write))
        _ = ioutil.WriteFile("domain2ip.json", write, 0644)
        fmt.Println("domain=" + name + "\t" + "ip=" + addr.String())
    }```
````

Comment: ["If the file does not exist, WriteFile creates it with permissions perm; otherwise WriteFile truncates it before writing."](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile) Don't use WriteFile in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I think the problem was, that you recreate the file every time you write to it. Opening the file with APPEND Mode and then writing to it will work. I also refactored the code a bit to get rid of the code repetitions. So just a bit of cleanup.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const (
    filename string = "domain2ip.json"
)

type DomainIP struct {
    Domain string `json:"domain"`
    IP     string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {
    trimdata := lines(fetchUrl("http://s.tutree.com:7635/v1/groups"))
    // fmt.Println(trimdata)
    for _, data := range trimdata {
        trim := lines(fetchUrl("http://s.tutree.com:7635/v1/" + data))
        // fmt.Println(trim)
        for _, domains := range trim {
            // fmt.Println(string(domains))
            domainIP, err := convertdomain2ip(string(domains))
            if (err == nil) {
                appendToFile(filename, domainIP)
            }
        }
    }
    // fmt.Println("file written successfully")
    os.Exit(0)
}

func fetchUrl(url string) string {
    result, err := http.Get(url)
    Error(err)
    defer result.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(result.Body)
    Error(err)
    return string(body)
}

func lines(s string) []string {
    return strings.Split(s, "\n")
}

func Error(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

func convertdomain2ip(name string) (*DomainIP, error) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Resolution error", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    typeconvert := addr.String()
    return &DomainIP{
        Domain: name,
        IP:     typeconvert}, nil
}

func appendToFile(filename string, data interface{}) {
    jsonData, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "")
    // fmt.Println(string(write))
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    if _, err := f.Write(jsonData); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Nonetheless for the resulting file to be a valid JSON document, you will have to separate the entries with commas and put the values into a JSON array (put `[` at the beginning of the file and `]` at the end of it.

If memory is no problem, you could also aggregate all `DomainIP` objects and write the file at the end. Then you could even use your previous write routine but at the end of the main method.

**Note 1**
My code will append to the file and create it only, if it not already exists. This means, you have to be aware that running the application multiple times, the data will always be appended to the original file, if you don't remove it first.

**Note 2**
Another option would have been to simply write to `stdout` instead of a file and send the result into a file with `>`. But this will work only in a bash like environment, like you have in Linux or MacOS.

```sh
go run main.go > domain2ip.json
```